# Google Cloud Speech API works on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-speech

Part of my web service is responsible for receiving user's audio and transcribing it to text using Google Cloud Speech API. It works perfectly on desktop (both on local machine and when deployed on web server), but returns the following error when I try to call it from the mobile phone (iPhone, Chrome): **google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 RecognitionAudio not set.**

JavaScript file writes a `Blob` with audio in `WAV` format and passes it to the memory:

```
        // Store the audio data in chunks as it is recorded
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event) => {
          chunks.push(event.data);
        });

        // When recording stops, create a blob from the chunks and send it to the server
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
          const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/wav" });
          const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          audio.src = url;
          uploadAudio(blob); // Send the audio data to the server
          chunks = []; // Clear the chunks array
        });
```

The following Python code processes it:

```
        audio_bytes = request.get_data()

        # Instantiate a client
        client = speech.SpeechClient()

        # Settings for Speech v1:
        # Initialize request arguments
        config = speech.RecognitionConfig()
        config.language_code = LANGUAGE
        config.model = "latest_long"
        config.enable_automatic_punctuation = True

        audio = speech.RecognitionAudio()
        audio.content = audio_bytes

        speech_request = speech.RecognizeRequest(
            config=config,
            audio=audio,
        )

        # Make the request
        response = client.recognize(request=speech_request)
```

According to the Google Cloud Speech documentation, `RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding` is not required for `WAV` audio, so I omitted it.
In case of requests from the mobile device I see `details = "Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding.."` in logs.
I checked that the audio data passed to the Python file is not empty, but apparently it has the wrong encoding if the audio is recorded on the mobile device.

What should I do to make it work both on desktop and mobile devices?

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996852/400-recognitionaudio-not-set-inactiverpcerror-google-text-to-speech-api) help you?